# How laravel pass object into method work?

Tags: php, laravel

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Bar; //Q1. where is include App\Bar?
//Q2. where is new Bar; ?


class Foo extends Controller
{

    public function foo(Request $request, Bar $bar){ //Q3. what is Bar $bar means? pass object into method?
        #1
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        #2
        $bar->barFunc();
    }   
}
```

I'm currently learning laravel and I notice laravel pass object into method

but I am very confuse how it works.

Here is my questions

1. we `use namespace App\Bar`, where is include file? (does laravel auto include file when you use namespace?)
2. where is `new Bar;` ?
3. how `foo(Request $request, Bar $bar)` works?

Does it pass object into method?

why not

```
foo(){
    $bar = new Bar;
}
```

Comment: 1. They're included via composer. More on composer [here](https://getcomposer.org/). 2. There is no `new Bar`. At least not in your example. It's your job to pass in an instance of `$bar` to the function. 3. Like any other function. [Type hints](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). And you don't do as you said `$bar = new Bar` directly in the function because [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Comment: Laravel uses an [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) container and it uses composer to `autoload` all your files for you, so you don't need to include them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/),

- The namespaced files are autoloaded via Composer using the [PSR-4 autoloading standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

> See example of [Implementations of PSR4 Autoloading](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md)

- The Laravel uses `type-hinting` of dependencies on your controller's methods. A common use-case for method injection is injecting the `Illuminate\Http\Request` instance into your controller methods. See more about [Dependency Injections in Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers)
- Laravel's [Container](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc) is called an IOC ("Inversion of Control") Container, and that's the case because it allows your control to happen at the top level of the app: you ask in your low-level code (controllers, implementation classes, etc.) for an instance of "mailer", and the container gives you one. Your low-level code doesn't care about which service is actually sending your mail--Mandrill? Mailgun? Sendmail? It doesn't matter, as long as the interface to the mailer class is the same.

> - See more about [Automatic Injections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container#automatic-injection)
> - Read more about [Method Injection - by Matt Stauffer](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-method-injection)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Answers:

1. Laravel is using [PSR-4 autoloading](https://laracasts.com/lessons/psr-4-autoloading)
2. You may want to read about [dependency injection and IoC](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container)
3. Same as 2.

Comment: so if i add autoload inside of composer.json I don't even need to use namespace